# Hyperlink to other worksheet using hyperlink function in excel 2003

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I want to hyperlink a worksheet from a worksheet containing a cell A1 having name of the sheet to be hyperlinked & friendly name.

For example I have a worksheet summary with Cell A1 having its value as "1"
& I have a worksheet named "1" to be hyperlink from summary & the friendly name is same as the worksheet to be hyperlinked.

Comment: This is very hard to understand - are you basically saying you want to link to a worksheet, where the hyper link name matches the work sheet name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HYPERLINK` function.

```
=HYPERLINK(link_location,friendly_name)
```

Here is the [source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hyperlink-HP005209116.aspx) for more information how to use this formula.